# android ViewTreeObserver, can not get right component from onclicklistener

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I have six `Linearlayout` inside a `GridLayout`:

```
     <GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridRollShutter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" />
</GridLayout

>
```

Then I use `gridLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` to check Layouts. Each of Layout I put a `ImageView`, and `setOnClickListener` to it. When it trigger, the listener always call the last component, although I click on the `ImageView` of the first Layout.
 here is my simpe code:

```
             gridLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        // remove the before treeObserver
                        gridLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                        // get the measure size of the grid layout
                        int width = gridLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
                        int height = gridLayout.getMeasuredHeight();


                        for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            View childView = inflater
                                        .inflate(
                                                R.layout.item_roller_horizontal_list,
                                                lnlTemp, false);
                        // loop to access each component
                            LinearLayout lnlTemp = (LinearLayout) gridLayout
                                    .getChildAt(i);

                            imgAlpha = (ImageView) childView
                                        .findViewById(R.id.imgRollerAlpha);
                            EnRollerShutterItem enRollerShutterItem = listRollerShutter
                                        .get(i);
                                imgAlpha.setTag(enRollerShutterItem
                                        .getDimPercent());

                                imgAlpha.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        Logger.error("tag: " + v.getTag());
                                        imgAlpha.startAnimation(animationEnlarge);
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });
                              ...............
```

When click Event was triggerd. I get the exactly tag, but the event always happen in the last `imageview` from last `Linearlayout`. I do not know why it happen.

Please give me a check out of problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When click Event was triggerd. I get the exactly tag, but the event
>   always happen in the last imageview from last Linearlayout. I do not
>   know why it happen.

I assume that by "event" you mean the animation that you start in the `OnClickListener` for that image. In this case, this could happen because in that `OnClickListener` you use the `imgAlpha` reference to start the animation. That reference will always point to the last `ImageView` due to the `for` loop. The solution is to use directly the `v` parameter because it represents the view on which the `OnClickListener` was set, the `ImageView`:

```
//...
Logger.error("tag: " + v.getTag());
v.startAnimation(animationEnlarge);
```

Comment: your are right, you help me know the problem : Because the "imaAlpha" is the " local variable" that I define in the top of code. So always reference to the last component. Thank u so much